# Postgres order row for exist field

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

I have table `users` and in this table I have column avatar which save path to user avatar. How I can order my query which starts from user which have avatar and after them which heven't.
Example:

Table:

```
 id|avatar|
___|______|
 1 |  p1  |
 2 |      |
 3 |      |
 4 |  p4  |
```

Result:

```
 id|avatar|
___|______|
 1 |  p1  |
 4 |  p4  |
 2 |      |
 3 |      |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that those blanks for `2` and `3` are NULLS then ORDER BY already does what you want; [ORDER BY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-ORDERBY) puts NULLS last by default when you sort ascending:

> If `NULLS LAST` is specified, null values sort after all non-null values; if `NULLS FIRST` is specified, null values sort before all non-null values. If neither is specified, the default behavior is `NULLS LAST` when `ASC` is specified or implied, and `NULLS FIRST` when `DESC` is specified (thus, the default is to act as though nulls are larger than non-nulls).

So something simple like:

```
order by avatar
```

would probably do the trick. If you want to be explicit about it, then:

```
order by avatar nulls last
```

or

```
order by avatar asc nulls last
```

Comment: Thanks! It's greate solution!